# Understanding the output of ovrpredict in LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm implementing a multiclass classification with Libsvm adopting a one versus all strategy. For this purpose, I used the `ovrtrain` and `ovrpredict` MATLAB functions:

```
model = ovrtrain(GroupTrain, TrainingSet,'t -0' );
[predicted_labels ac decv] = ovrpredict(testY, TestSet, model);
```

The output of `ovrpredict` is as follows

```
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 95% (19/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)
```

I have 10 classes, I'm new to libsvm so I guess that those accuracies correspond to the classification accuracy of each class. However, I don't understand what is the difference between this output and the value of the accuracy `ac` returned by `ovrpredict`, which is 60%.

```
ac =

    0.6000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both values are quite different from each other. Accuracy is the output of `svmpredict()` function, which tells you how your test data set is fitting to that specific class while `ac` gives you accuracy of input test class-labels (testY in your case) w.r.t predicted class-labels.

Lets, have a look inside `overpredict` function and see how these accuracy values are being generated.

```
function [pred, ac, decv] = ovrpredict(y, x, model)
```

From definition, we can see, we have 3 input parameters.

1. y = Class labels
2. x = Test sata set
3. model = A struct containing 10 models for 10 different classes.

   labelSet = model.labelSet;

labelSet extracts labelSet (unique class-labels). In your case, you will have 10 unique labels, depending how you set while defining 10 separate classes of test data.

```
labelSetSize = length(labelSet)
```

Here you get number of classes (10 in your case).

```
 models = model.models;
```

'models' variable will contain all training models (10 in your case).

```
decv= zeros(size(y, 1), labelSetSize)
```

Here, decv matrix has been created to keep decision probablities of each test data value.

```
for i=1:labelSetSize
  [l,a,d] = svmpredict(double(y == labelSet(i)), x, models{i});
  decv(:, i) = d * (2 * models{i}.Label(1) - 1);
end
```

Here, we pass our test data from svmpredict function for each generated model. In your case, this loop will iterate 10 times and generate classification Accuracy of test for each specific class. For example, **Accuracy = 90% (18/20) (classification)** indicates that 18 out of 20 rows of your test data set matches to that specific class.

***Please note, in multi-class SVM, you can't make a decision based on Accuracy values. You will need `Pred` and `ac` values to make individual or overall estimate respectively.***

`double(y == labelSet(i)` changes multi-class labels to single class labels by by checking which labels in y belong to a specific class (where iterator i is pointing). it will output either 0 or 1 for unmatched or matched cases respectively. Hence output label vector will contain either 0's or 1's thus corresponding to single class SVM.

`decv(:, i) = d * (2 * models{i}.Label(1) - 1)` labels the decision values -ve(unhealthy) or +ve(healthy) depending upon the single-class label values in respective trained model. `models{i}.Label(1)` contains only 2 types of values .i.e. 0 (for unmatched cases) or 1(for matched cases). Hence `(2 * models{i}.Label(1) - 1)`will always evaluate to 1 or -1, therefore, labelling the decision value healthy or unhealthy.

```
[tmp,pred] = max(decv, [], 2);
pred = labelSet(pred);
```

max returns two column vectors, 1st (tmp) containing the maximum decision value in each row and end (pred) respective row (or class) index.Hence, we are only interested in class index, we discard tmp variable.

```
ac = sum(y==pred) / size(x, 1);
```

Finally, we will calculate `ac` by checking how many predicted labels match input test labels and dividing the sum with number of test classes.

***In your case `ac=0.6` means 6 out of 10 test labels match predicted labels or 4 labels have been predicted otherwise.***

I hope, it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed reply. It's very helpful I really appreciate that.